# How to Execute Build command in jenkins(Ubuntu)

Tags: java, selenium, ubuntu, jenkins

I need to integrate a simple selenium script with Jenkins.
Can someone please help me to get a shell script code to update in the build section.

Currently, I am tried with run.bat file which returns the following error.

```
Building in workspace /home/mythos/loremine/Automation_Workspace/JenkinsDemo
[JenkinsDemo] $ cmd /c call /tmp/jenkins2455301809650179322.bat
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd" (in directory "/home/mythos/loremine/Automation_Workspace/JenkinsDemo"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:250)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:219)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:937)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:455)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:109)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:66)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1853)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:427)
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu, you need to use `Execute Shell` not `Execute Windows Batch Command`

[image]

Comment: Can we use the same code `Java –cp bin;lib/* org.testng.TestNG testNg.xml` in .sh file.

Comment: Getting below console error message in `Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /home/mythos/loremine/Automation_Workspace/JenkinsDemo
[JenkinsDemo] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins959706295364739197.sh
+ run.sh
/tmp/jenkins959706295364739197.sh: 2: /tmp/jenkins959706295364739197.sh: run.sh: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE`.

Selected Execute Shell, and updated run.bat as run.sh

Comment: You don't need to make run.sh file, just type `java –cp bin;lib/* org.testng.TestNG testNg.xml` on Execute shell

Comment: In order for this to work, however, the following operation must be possible in the terminal: `cd /home/mythos/loremine/Automation_Workspace/JenkinsDemo` and `java –cp bin;lib/* org.testng.TestNG testNg.xml`

Comment: Hi Thanks :-). I am still getting the below error with the execution.

`[JenkinsDemo] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins7505565238733559593.sh
+ cd /home/mythos/loremine/Automation_Workspace/JenkinsDemo
+ java –cp bin
Error: Could not find or load main class –cp
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure` 

Please advise

Comment: you need to copy all file include `lib/*` to `/home/mythos/loremine/Automation_Workspace/JenkinsDemo`

Comment: or before `java ~~` command you can add `cd <executable folder>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205430/discussion-between-sree-and-roy-cha).

Answer (score 0):

remove / in your command as given below. It may solve your problems.

```
 cmd /c call tmp/jenkins2455301809650179322.bat
```

Comment: I am not provided the command anywhere. The only code updated is `Java –cp bin;lib/* org.testng.TestNG testNg.xml` in run.bat file

Comment: In jenkins configuration, it looks like. please try with updated job configuration